# Access ng-repeat scope within controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say I have

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <span ng-show="editing">i.something</span>
  <span ng-show="!editing">i.something</span>
  <a ng-click="dosomething(i)">click</a>
</div>
```

in the controller I have:

```
$scope.dosomething = function (model){
   //do stuff
   editing = false;
}
```

How can I access the variable of only the iteration of the ng-repeat, i've tried passing editing through as a parameter to `dosomething` i've tried accessing it through $scope.editing, I've been looking through $rootScope documentation. Can't work it out.

I acknowledge I could add `editing` as a parameter of `i` but I'd rather not touch the model unnecessarily if there is a way to access each scope respectively without changing editing for the other iterations.

Comment: which type of data your items does contain?
on which condition you want show your which data?

your //do stuff part here must contain condition on which you can set editing to true n false. but I'm confused with your question so can't provide you a solution. be more clear with what is to be achieved...

Answer (score 1):

Your `dosomething()` function is run in the context of the parent scope (thus affects all items).
So, you should remove `$scope.editing = false` from the body of `dosomething()`.

Then, inside your `ngClick` expression, you can insert `editing=false` which will be evaluated in the context of the child-scope created by `ngRepeat` for each item, and **not** affect other items.

E.g.:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
    ...
    <a ng-click="editing=false;dosomething(i)">click</a>
</div>

$scope.dosomething = function (model){
    // Do stuff
    // Don't touch `editing` here
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/g8y5H/)**.

Comment: Sorry been afk for a week, Thats a feasible solution for other scenarios but that time I think I was trying to change editing based on conditionals inside the called function.

Comment: @Kiee: You could return a value and set editing based on that: `ng-click="editing=dosomething(i)"`

Answer (score 0):

the ng-repeat directive creates child scopes and binds them to every "repeat" element. Therefore, you can access your "editing" variable in the child scope this way.

```
$scope.dosomething = function (model){
   //do stuff
 angular.element(model.currentTarget).scope().editing = flase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <span ng-show="i.editing">i.something</span>
  <span ng-show="!i.editing">i.something</span>
  <a ng-click="dosomething(i)">click</a>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.dosomething = function (model){
   //do stuff
   model.editing = false;
}
```

Where model refers to the ng-repeat item's (i) scope.